# how to change variable value in links with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the variable values in all links on the page.
If the links looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com?type=iPhone&userId=1">The 1 link</a>
<a href="http://www.mypage2.com?type=iPhone&userId=1">The 2 link</a>
```

I want to change `type=iPhone` to `type=Android`. But I don't know how to find the `type=iPhone` so I can replace it?

What is the best way of doing this?
Thanks.

Ok, this is my real code.

What Im trying to do is to check for the user agent and change the appType=iPhone if it is an android.

```
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if (ua.indexOf("Android") >= 0) {
        var androidversion = parseFloat(ua.slice(ua.indexOf("Android") + 8));
        if (androidversion < 4.0) {
           alert("You have an old Android");

        }
        var apptype='appType=Android';
        alert(apptype);

        $("a[href*='appType=iPhone']").attr("href", function () {
        return this.href.replace("appType=iPhone", "appType=Android");
        });
    }
    else
    {   
        var apptype='appType=iPhone';
        alert(apptype); 


    }
```

And with this it is not changing the appType=iPhone at all, I dont know what Im missing?

Comment: first of all, give your `<a>` tag an `id`

Comment: @ShivanRaptor why..? i think thats not nescessary

Comment: Are the links rendered serverside?

Comment: i misread the OP question, no `id` needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done the way you imagine, but seriously - question if that is the best way to achieve your goal.

Using jQuery, you can find elements using an [attribute-contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('a[href*="type=iPhone"]');
```

The `*=` says "attribute contains"

Then you can just replace the href:

```
$('a[href*="type=iPhone"]').attr("href",function(){
     $(this).attr('href').replace('type=iPhone','type=Android');
});
```

However, you should consider there may be a better way to do this. For example if you remove that `type=iPhone` attribute from the `href` and instead decide which `type=*` to append when the user clicks the link, then you dont need to do all that messing about finding and replacing.

For example, starting with this HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com?userId=1">The 1 link</a>
<a href="http://www.mypage2.com?userId=1">The 2 link</a>
```

Then assuming a variable which contains which `type` is active:

```
var osType = 'iPhone'; // change to 'Android' if need be or dynamically - whatever!
```

Use this jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.href = href + '&type=' + osType;
});
```

Live example of this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/K7UNg/1/

Comment: Ok, thanks.
But what if it doesnt end with that, what if I have more variable after that one? Ill change my question. Just remove the $ and it will find type=iPhone? I will try!

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson - Use an ["attribute contains"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector instead. (See update to my answer).

Comment: Thanks, I have tested with the above suggestions but I cant get it working.
So I will change my question again :-)

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson - see update - ive added a jsfiddle example to demonstrate!

Comment: Thanks, but the example is not working for me? No alert or anything.

Comment: Sorry, it did work, was clicking the button and not the link :-)

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson - on which browser? (I assume Android or iPhone - neither of which I can test)

Comment: Ok I tested in my page but it is not working with your last example, I guess that its because I load the pages with ajax?

Comment: So I guess that I have to go with the change example, could you please see my changed question and see why that is not working, thanks.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson - its probably not working because ive used a old-fashioned way of assigning events using `click` - these wont work of the html is dynamically loaded. Use `on` instead - See update

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20231/discussion-between-jamiec-and-claes-gustavsson)

Answer (score 5):

You can use an [attribute ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to find links with an `href` ending with "iPhone" and then use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to change the value:

```
$("a[href$='iPhone']").attr("href", function () {
    return this.href.replace("iPhone", "Android");
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/6jD6d/).

**Update**

Now that you've updated the question and the URLs no longer end with the string you're looking for, you can use an [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) instead:

```
$("a[href*='iPhone']").attr("href", function () {
    return this.href.replace("iPhone", "Android");
});
```

Here's another [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/6jD6d/1/).